# Update SEO properties to a single page programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, publishing-page, 2019, seo

How to update SEO properties to a single publishing page programmatically?

The SEO properties can be updated manually through the ribbon, but how to do it programmatically?

I'm using SharePoint 2019 on-premise.

Comment: Sorry, it's a delayed reply but I don't see option to update SEO properties in the ribbon in SharePoint Server 2019 (on-premise). How are you able to update it?

Answer (score 0):

Find this articel:[Update SEO Properties in SharePoint programmatically](https://wiliammbr.com/updating-seo-properties-in-sharepoint-programmatically/), hope it will help you.

Comment: That is not working.